# Переместить один label при наведении курсора мышки на другой label

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qlabel

Имеется форма с QTabWidget, в котором **`2`** `label`. Нужно при наведении на 2-ой `label` чтобы у первого менялось местоположение.

Не могу понять логику создания.

Смог только переопределить метод `enterEvent(`)  `QLabel`, в котором вывожу в консоль имя объекта на котором фокус.

Как обратиться из этого метода к объекту другого класса не понимаю, спасибо за время которое потратите на ЛикБез для меня.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**untitled.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
            print(self.objectName())

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(297, 222)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 291, 211))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label_2 = MyLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 151, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label = MyLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 151, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нужно переместить правее"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Наводим сюда"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

#from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(297, 222)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 291, 211))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")

        self.label_2 = MyLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 151, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label = MyLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 151, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нужно переместить правее"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Наводим сюда"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print(self.objectName(), "<- enterEvent")
        if self.objectName() == "label":
            self.window().label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 151, 16))
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print(self.objectName(), "<- leaveEvent")  
        if self.objectName() == "label":
            self.window().label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 151, 16))        
        super().leaveEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    '''    
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Выручаешь!!!